# Parallel Stream gives null items, How to do in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I'm getting some weird results when trying to use a parallel stream and I know a workaround, but it doesn't seem ideal

```
// Create the set "selected"
somethingDao.getSomethingList().parallelStream()
                .filter(something -> !selected.contains(something.getSomethingId()))
                .forEach(something ->
                                somethingSubGroupDTO.addFilterDTO(
                                        new FilterDTO(something.getSomethingName(), something.getSomethingDescription(), false))
                );
selected.clear();
```

`somethingDao.getSomethingList` returns a `List`

`selected` is a `HashSet<Integer>` that is not modified during this operation.

`somethingSubGroupDTO.addFilterDTO` is a helper function that adds to an unsynchronized List. This is the problem.  As an unsynchronzed list I get less items in the list than expected AND some items are null.  If I turn this into a synchronized list it works.  Obviously adding lock contention to a parallel stream is not ideal.

At the high level I know it's possible to do this in such a way that each stream will do its own processing and when they join they will aggregate. (At least I can imagine such a process without lock contention)  However since I'm new to Java 8 stream processing I'm not aware of how.  How do I do this same operation without having contention at a single point?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `forEach` and collect your Stream into a `List` instead:

```
somethingDao.getSomethingList().parallelStream()
                .filter(something -> !selected.contains(something.getSomethingId()))
                .map(something -> new FilterDTO(something.getSomethingName(), something.getSomethingDescription(), false))
                .collect(toList());
```

Then, you can set the returned list directly into your `somethingSubGroupDTO` object, instead of adding one item at a time.

Comment: And this returns a list that I can then add to my collection at the end, rather than one at a time?

Comment: @CarlosBribiescas Exactly

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question.  As a follow up, is it possible to designate what list it should aggregate to so that at the end it auto adds?  Not necessary, just curious.

Comment: @Carlos Bribiescas: you can use something like `… .collect(collectingAndThen(toList(), targetList::addAll));`

Comment: Nice, but why does this solve the problem?   What _is_ the problem?